# After ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(), why failed to call Windows API SetDisplayConfig()?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

This is a System service. After `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()`, I can call `CreateProcessAsUser()` successfully. But it fails to call one Windows API `SetDisplayConfig()`. The error is 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED). Please see the code below.

```
// This function is called in a System service.  
void SetDisplayToExtendMode()
{
    DWORD dwSessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
    if (dwSessionId == 0xFFFFFFFF)
    {
        qCritical() << "Failed to get active console session Id when setting extend mode for display!";
    }

    HANDLE hUserToken = NULL;
    if (WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId, &hUserToken) == FALSE)
    {
        qCritical() << "Failed to query user token when setting extend mode for display!";
    }

    HANDLE hTheToken = NULL;
    if (DuplicateTokenEx(hUserToken, TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, 0, SecurityImpersonation, TokenPrimary, &hTheToken) == TRUE)
    {

        if (ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hTheToken) == TRUE)
        {
            DWORD dwCreationFlags = HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;

            LPVOID pEnv = NULL;
            if (CreateEnvironmentBlock(&pEnv, hTheToken, TRUE) == TRUE)
            {
                dwCreationFlags |= CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT;
            }

            // Way 1: Call Windows API directly. 
            // Fail. Error code is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED
            LONG errCode = SetDisplayConfig(0, NULL, 0, NULL, SDC_TOPOLOGY_EXTEND | SDC_APPLY);
            if (errCode != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                qCritical() << "Failed to set Windows Display to Extended mode! Error is " << errCode;
                if (errCode == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
                {
                    qCritical() << "ACCESS denied!";
                }
            }

            STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
            PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES Security1 = { sizeof(Security1) };
            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES Security2 = { sizeof(Security2) };


            std::wstring command = L"C:\\Users\\SomeUser\\Desktop\\QT_Projects\\build\\release\\TestSetDisplay.exe";
            TCHAR commandLine[MAX_PATH];
            _tcscpy_s(commandLine, MAX_PATH, command.c_str());

            // Way 2： This way can be successful. 
            BOOL bResult = CreateProcessAsUser(
                hTheToken,
                NULL,   // (LPWSTR)(path),
                (LPWSTR)(commandLine),
                &Security1,
                &Security2,
                FALSE,
                dwCreationFlags,
                pEnv,
                NULL,
                &si,
                &pi
                );

            if (!bResult)
            {
                qCritical() << "Failed to CreateProcessAsUser()";
            }

            RevertToSelf();

            if (pEnv)
            {
                DestroyEnvironmentBlock(pEnv);
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(hTheToken);
    }
    CloseHandle(hUserToken);
}
```

So, after `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()`, how to call Windows API `SetDisplayConfig()` successfully?
Alternatively, in one System service, how to call one Windows API as a user? (For this case, the purpose of calling `SetDisplayConfig()` is to set the display mode to Extend mode. This display mode is set per user. So, as a system service, it may need to `impersonateLoggedOnUser()` first.)

Comment: Probably because the impersonated user doesn't have access to the service's registry (which is probably what HKEY_CURRENT_USER is pointing to and probably where SetDisplayConfig saves its per-user setting).

Answer (score 1):

from [SetDisplayConfig](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569533(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation

> ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED The caller does not have access to the console
>   session. This error occurs if the calling process does not have access
>   to the current desktop or is running on a remote session.

and you wrote

> This is a System service.

but System service have no access to interactive desktop. so you need call it from interactive session

Comment: Exactly.  See also https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110928-00/?p=9533 ; impersonation is all about the access control model, it isn't an all-purpose solution.

Comment: @RbMm, probably you are right. To be simple, the question is, **can a System service set the active user's Display mode to Extend?**   What do you mean by "call it from interactive session"? Which windows APIs need to be called?

Comment: about Terminal session look [TokenSessionId][1], sessions have own copy of win32k.sys mapped into its address space (in a region called "Session Space"). as result different global vars. problem here in `gProtocolType`, look [this][2] - you got c0000022(STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED). so impossible from service process. also [look][3] related issue about `gProtocolType`
  [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379626(v=vs.85).aspx
  [2]: http://i.imgur.com/blIRidH.png
  [3]: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20866/ClearType-over-Remote-Desktop-in-Windows-XP?msg=2511636